# Angular2 TS TS2322: Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'Post[]'.

Tags: angular, typescript

[githubrepo](https://github.com/patrickgomes1968/Angular2Assignment)

I get the above error in the CLI console, even though Post has been defined as an interface/type:
user.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {PostService} from '../services/post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'user',
  template: #`,
  providers: [PostService],
})
export class UserComponent  { 
    name: string;
    email: string;
    address: address;
    hobbies: string[];
    showhobbies: boolean;
    posts: Post[];

`   constructor(private postService: PostService) {
        ...
        this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
            this.posts = posts;
            console.log(posts);
        });
    }
}

interface Post{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
}
```

post.service.js:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class PostService {
    constructor(private http: Http){
        console.log("PostService initialized");
    }

    getPosts(){
        return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .map(res => res.json);
    }
}
```

The console.log outputs a function-literal instead of the expected array of posts fetched from the REST API.:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use type when defining your service but the real problem is that `res.json` should be `res.json()`:

```
getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```